# Gstreamer multiudpsink broadcast over all subnets

Tags: gstreamer

Below is my actual pipeline for sender and reciever. I would like to stream over all subnets (from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255. I would like that the receiver can decode the stream whatever is ip is : 192.168.1.10 or 192.168.1.235 or...
How do I have to use multiudpsink to do that?

**SENDER**

```
appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.2 port=5200 sync=false
```

**RECIEVER**

```
udpsrc ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert !d3dvideosink sync=false
```

Comment: Read up on what IP multicast is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Thanks but it is not my question.